# Passing json object in a call to android javascript method?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to call a method say success(message) of javascript from android activity. I do this as follows:

```
webView.loadUrl(javascript:success(message));
```

But this message = JSON object from the http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=12844782&u=c response. So how do i make the right url (message) in android?

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should read all content from specified url (http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=12844782&u=c). do it using HttpClient or URL connection. let me know if you don't know how to do this. save the content to some var (say message)
2. then you should invoke the following: webView.loadUrl("javascript:success(" + message + ")");

almost the same as you wrote :)